# How to extract media.type from a PCAP using tshark?

Tags: linux, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I have a pcap file and that contain some http media.type (pdf) . I can able to export media type from wireshark gui. 
I tried
`tshark -r run.pcap -T fields -e media.type > sample.raw`
but no result.

Please help me to figure out the issue .

Answer (score 0):

The content type field's name, for HTTP, is `http.content_type`, not `media.type`.  Try

```
tshark -r run.pcap -T fields -e http.content_type > sample.raw
```